# How to customize json wrapped key for class if I am not able to mark that class with annotation JsonTypeInfo?

Tags: java, json, jackson, wrapper

I have code like this:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.*;

public class MyPojo {
    int id;
    public int getId()
    { return this.id; }

    public void setId(int id)
    { this.id = id; }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyPojo mp = new MyPojo();
        mp.setId(4);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);        
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(mp));
    }
}
```

It works expected:

```
{"MyPojo":{"id":4}}
```

But I want to customize that name. I am not able to mark `MyPojo`  with `@JsonTypeInfo` becausee i take this class from library.

Is there way to do it in jackson?

Comment: Tried to subclass your `MyPojo` and adding the annotation to the subclass?

Comment: @Usagi Miyamoto, it is a good idea but I am not sure if we could do it because our classes are generated via thrift and we can't change signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ObjectWriter` also specifically for this class:

```
MyPojo mp = new MyPojo();
mp.setId(4);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer().withRootName("TestPojo");
System.out.println(writer.writeValueAsString(mp));
```

Comment: Good idea. Do you have smth like this about deserialization?

Comment: You can use `mapper.reader().withRootName("TestPojo").forType(MyPojo.class)`

Comment: If root name is always going to be same, then yes. Rest depends on use case.

Comment: I need a solution which will work the same after next invocation of  **mapper.reader()**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` you could just create a new class like this:

```
public class MyWrapper {

    private MyPojo myName = new MyPojo();

    public void setId(int id) { myName.setId(id); }
}
```

If you create a JSON out of an object of this type, the attribute will have the name *myName*, e.g.: `{"myName" : {"id" : 4} }`.

Comment: I am not able to do it

Comment: My classes generated by thrift